# Laravel 5.5 using different email setting other than ENV for sending email

Tags: php, laravel-5

In laravel 5.5.4 i want a specific function to send mail via different mail setting other then mentioned in `.env` file.

I've tried searching but most of the places it's mentioned with `swift` which is now deprecated.

Comment: you can override those settings. you can use simple php mail or mailtrap or mailgun etc

Comment: Take a look here for the available built in drivers. I use mailgun, its free and easy to use. I haven't tried the others though. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the email, simply call `config()->set("mail.driver", $driver)`:

```
public function sendNonEnvEmail(){
  // If you want to log this email instead of sending it
  config()->set("mail.driver", "log");
  \Mail::send(...);
}
```

Now I'm not sure if you need to reset the email driver following this, but if that's the case, you can call do the following:

```
\Mail::send(...);
config()->set("mail.driver", env("MAIL_DRIVER", "smtp"));
```

That will reset the driver back to it's default value from the `.env` file, or `smtp` it's `MAIL_DRIVER` isn't set.

**-- Edit --**

> Configuration values that are set at run-time are only set for the current request, and will not be carried over to subsequent requests.

So you *don't* need to reset it, but if you need to send more than one email in a request, it may become necessary, depending on the order of emails.